# drupal internal server error

Tags: drupal, internal

I had created a folder in my site, and uploaded drupal in it. But when I access it, the following error is coming

```
    Internal Server Error

 The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable 
to complete your request.

 Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@xxxxxx.xx and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

 More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Comment: Have you already tried removing the .htaccess file (in the root folder) that's provided with Drupal?

Comment: Hello Wim Vandersmissen, when i removed htaccess file, the installation page appears but without css file, i mean the page looks as if it has no css file linked.

Answer (score 2):

There are literally thousands of things that can be wrong

- Do you have access to the webserver logs? Check /log/apache/error.log for errors.
- Have you already configured drupal correctly? Normally, when you surf to the drupal root directory, you get presented with an installer message.
- Does your server support PHP?

I'd recommend any of the following:

- Checking that you meet the Drupal requirements
- Re-uploading the whole Drupal folder
- Testing the Drupal folder (is this a custom installation, or just straight from the drupal website?) on local LAMPP webserver.

Comment: Hi Jeroen.I don't have access to error log files,this is a new installation and no installer message had appeared.There is already a website(php-mysql) and i wanted to work in drupal, so created a folder in the existing site.

Comment: Did you already create an empty database for drupal? http://drupal.org/documentation/install

Comment: Yes created, but these things are required after getting in to installation page,but here i am not even able view the first page itself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to run Drupal for the first time (ie run the installer), have you followed the pre-install setup?

Here's Drupal's "Quick install guide for beginners": http://drupal.org/documentation/install/beginners

Since you've already uploaded the code and you have your domain set up, you can probably skip down to the big labelled "Create the configuration file and grant permissions".

The first thing in this section is to create your settings.php file. Drupal won't work without this. You also need to set its file permissions to that Drupal's installer can update it.

My guess is that this is why you're getting the error. Follow the instructions on the page I linked you to above and you should be okay.

You'll also need to have a database ready for use by Drupal. The Drupal installer will populate the DB tables, but you need to at least have the empty DB ready for it to use.

Hope that helps.